# Excluding string items from an array

Tags: linux, shell

I have a script where I want to remove items from an array specified in a second list, I have the following code but it doesn't work:

```
db_exclude=( 'information_schema' 'mysql' )

databases=$(/usr/bin/mysql --defaults-extra-file=/etc/unimicrosys/sqlbackup/my.cnf -e 'show databases' -s --skip-column-names)
length=${#databases[@]}

for exclude in $db_exclude[@]; do
    for (( i=0; i<$length; i++ )); do
        echo $i
        if [[ databases[$i] = $exclude ]]; then
            unset $databases[$i];
        fi;
    done
done
```

Comment: you got a +1 from me.

Comment: I think @parkydr has spotted your omission (`${databases[$i]}`). In the future, you might see where the problem is by using the shell debugging features, `set -vx` or just to show variable expansion, `set -x`. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah debugging is hard for me, I am used to C# and visual studio! Thanks for the help

Comment: To learn about it, use `set -x`, and just execute test cmds that use variables on the cmd line. YOu'll get the hang of it quickly. `set -vx` is more advanced as it displays the next 'statement' to be executed and then all of the `-x` output. So you see what code is going to be executed, and then the execution. 'Statement' is probably the wrong word, as a 4000 line `while .... done` will be displayed (in my definition of a statement, and then all of the internal processing. Will also help to to change the debug prompt to show current line #, i.e. `PS4='${LINENO} :'` .. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't check the mysql command is producing an array, but this works if databases is set to an array

```
db_exclude=( 'information_schema' 'mysql' )

databases=( 'aaaa' 'information_schema' 'bbb' 'mysql' 'ccc' )

length=${#databases[@]}

for exclude in ${db_exclude[@]}; do
    for (( i=0; i<$length; i++ )); do
        echo $i
        if [[ ${databases[$i]} = $exclude ]]; then
            unset databases[$i];
        fi;
    done
done

echo ${databases[@]}
```

I found the problem by running the script with `bash -x` which showed the for loop was only executing once and the comparisons were with the text "database[0]", not the value.